# Apply change event in hidden input field updated dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply the change event when the value of a hidden input field changes, this hidden input field is being updated dynamically.

Followings are my code,

Hidden input: `<input name="hiddenInput" type="hidden" value="25194">`

Change event's jQuery code I'm using currently:

```
$('input[name="hiddenInput"]').bind("change", function() {
        var hiddenValue = $('input[name="hiddenInput"]').val();
        alert(hiddenValue);
});
```

***Note:*** I know there are a lot of questions already being posted and answered all over the internet but everyone is talking about getting hidden field's value when a button clicks etc.
I know if I change the attribute from hidden to text this may be getting to work, but this is my system's requirement so I can't change.
I haven't found my answer yet any ware, kindly do help me.

Comment: How is the hidden input field's value updated? If it is updated **programmatically**, you will need to invoke the change event manually, i.e. `.trigger('change')`, because the change event is only fired upon direct user input/manipulation.

Comment: The `change` event refers to the `value` property of the element being updated, not the `type` attribute. If you need to listen for that, then you will have to use one of the DOM listeners or a Mutation Observer. I'd suggest the latter as it's more up to date

Comment: Actually I am working on a PHP's framework(customized) vTiger v6 and there are HECK a lot of JS files, I can't open each and every file to look for a single line where its being updated. Although I did check most of the main files but I couldn't found it.

Answer (score 0):

> this hidden input field is being updated dynamically

If consider your `hidden input` update by `socket` or `ajax` or *etc* you need to add `.change()` on this input when it updated:

```js
$('input[name="hiddenInput"]').on("change", function() {
  var hiddenValue = $('input[name="hiddenInput"]').val();
  console.log(hiddenValue);
});

setInterval(function() { // simulate data update automatically!
  let v = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
  $('input[name="hiddenInput"]').val(v).change(); // -> just add this!
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="hiddenInput" type="hidden" value="25194">
```

---

**Second solution**

*Also you can compare your old value with new dynamic value like below example, or store your old value in `data-value`.*

```js
$('input[name="hiddenInput"]').on("change", function() {
  var hiddenValue = $('input[name="hiddenInput"]').val();
  console.log(hiddenValue);
});

setInterval(function() {
  let newValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
  let oldValue = $('input[name="hiddenInput"]').val();
  $('#old').text(oldValue)
  $('input[name="hiddenInput"]').val(newValue);
  if (newValue != oldValue) {
    console.log('changed')
  }

}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="hiddenInput" type="text" value="25194"> <!-- change type to hidden later -->
<span>Old value is: </span><span id="old"></span>
```